# bootstrap form duplicated content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have page structure on desktop like this:

```
<form>
___________________________________________________
|                                                 |
|                                  [] checkbox    |
|             <div>TITLE</div>                    |
|            <div>SUBTITLE</div>                  |
|_________________________________________________|
</form>
```

On mobile i want to have like this :

```
<form>
____________________
|                  |
|   <div></div>    |
|   <div></div>    |
|   []checkbox     |
|__________________|
</form>
```

code :

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right visible-lg">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            SUBTITLE
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right hidden-lg">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

tried to play with `.visible-lg` `.hidden-lg` and etc. but problem is that checkbox is same (cloned - same `name`, `id`, `class`) and when submitting form they are confusing all the logic. If first I checked but second not, in post I still get that it's checked.

What should i do in this case ?

Checkeboxes are toggles (bootstrapetoggle.com)

Comment: If they are in same row, then you can use PULL and PUSH classes.

Comment: @AnilTalla in the drawing, each new line is a row. So they are not in the same row

Comment: Write a javascript function to remove one of the element, call that function from onload and resize events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox. You can set the order of any element inside of it. In this case, the default is `order: 1;` (and ties are solved by real order), and by setting the checkbox to `order: 2;` it shifts down under the other two.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #withcheckbox {
    order: 2;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dm8y7d6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

keeping you approach, the easiest way to solve is to enclose the fields in 2 different forms, with the same action. Something like:

```
<form action="/myaction"> <!-- sm-hidden -->
[] check
<div></div>
<div></div>
<submit />
</form>

<form action="/myaction"> <!-- lg-hidden -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
[] check
<submit />
</form>
```

the id needs to be different, but all you need on server side is the name attribute, not the id

-- EDIT --

if you don't mind use javascript to compose the page, you can use an html template:

```js
function useTemplate(id) {
  var myTemplate = document.getElementById('myTemplate'),
    normalContent = document.getElementById(id),
    clonedTemplate = myTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
    normalContent.appendChild(clonedTemplate);
}

useTemplate('first-form');useTemplate('second-form');
```

```html
<!-- Template Content -->
<template id="myTemplate">
<div><input /></div>
<div><input /></div>
<div><input /></div>
<div><input /></div>
</template>

<!-- Normal Content -->
<form>
<fieldset>
<input type='checkbox'/>
<div id="first-form">
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

<form>
<fieldset>
<div id="second-form">
</div>
<input type='checkbox'/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: that's the problem, that form is very large, this is only top of the form. So duplicating form is not good at this point. btw thanks

Comment: -- EDIT -- If you don't mind create the forms via javascript, you can do something like the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this--

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                            ---------
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                            +++++++++
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                     checkbox[]
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks, but all text's in div should be `.text-center` and checkbox shouldn't be in the same row.

Comment: check at the snippet the check box is not in the same row as the other two elements rather all the three elements are wrapped in a outer row. you can easily use .text-centre for the elements